# Proper replacement for usage of the Sun internal com.sun.image.codec.jpeg package?

Tags: java, jpeg, encode, decode

We have some code kicking around that uses this old internal Sun package for manipulating images, essentially encoding JPEGs to a specific size and quality after reading in / decoding from an inputstream.  Code examples below.  I would appreciate a best practice replacement example using proper java.* or javax.* APIs.

```
private void encodeJPEG(BufferedImage bi, BufferedOutputStream out, float quality) throws
  ImageFormatException, IOException {
 JPEGImageEncoder encoder = JPEGCodec.createJPEGEncoder(out);
 JPEGEncodeParam param = encoder.getDefaultJPEGEncodeParam(bi);
 param.setQuality(quality, false);
 param.setDensityUnit(DENSITY_UNIT);
 param.setXDensity(DENSITY);
 param.setYDensity(DENSITY);
 encoder.setJPEGEncodeParam(param);
 encoder.encode(bi);
}


private void initJPEG(File jpegFile) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException,
  IOException {
FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(jpegFile);
try {
  JPEGImageDecoder decoder = JPEGCodec.createJPEGDecoder(inputStream);
  buffImage = decoder.decodeAsBufferedImage();
}
.....error handling.....
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't tried this approach, but you can take a look the [Java Image I/O API](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/imageio/index.html). The [JPEGImageWriteParam class](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/imageio/plugins/jpeg/JPEGImageWriteParam.html) would be of particular interest.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, sort of.I did this tests , for measuring the differences in encoding and write to file with JpegCodec,ImageIO(without parameters),ImageIO(with parameters).

```
    int numTest = 200;
    Robot robot = new Robot();
    BufferedImage image = robot.createScreenCapture(new Rectangle(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize()));

    //JPEGCODEC
    long t1 = System.currentTimeMillis();
    ByteArrayOutputStream ba = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    JPEGImageEncoder encoder = JPEGCodec.createJPEGEncoder(ba);
    JPEGEncodeParam param = encoder.getDefaultJPEGEncodeParam(image);
    param.setQuality(0.75f, false);
    encoder.setJPEGEncodeParam(param);

    File f = new File("TestJPEGCODEC");
    f.mkdir();
    for (int i = 0; i < numTest; i++) {
        encoder.encode(image);
        f = new File("TestJPEGCODEC\\test" + i + ".jpg");
        FileOutputStream fo = new FileOutputStream(f);
        fo.write(ba.toByteArray());
        fo.flush();
        ba.reset();

    }
    long t2 = System.currentTimeMillis();
    System.out.println("JPEGCODEC");
    System.out.println("Total time:: " + (t2 - t1) + " average time:: " + (t2 - t1) / numTest);

    //NORMAL IMAGEIO
    t1 = System.currentTimeMillis();
    f = new File("TestImageIO");
    f.mkdir();
    for (int i = 0; i < numTest; i++) {
        f = new File("TestImageIO\\test" + i + ".jpg");
        ImageIO.write(image, "jpg", f);
    }
    t2 = System.currentTimeMillis();
    System.out.println("ImageIO");
    System.out.println("Total time:: " + (t2 - t1) + " average time:: " + (t2 - t1) / numTest);

    Iterator<ImageWriter> it = ImageIO.getImageWritersByFormatName("jpg");
    ImageWriter writer = null;
    while (it.hasNext()) {
        writer = it.next();
    }
    //IMAGEIO EXPLICIT MODE
    t1 = System.currentTimeMillis();
    ImageWriteParam par = writer.getDefaultWriteParam();
    par.setCompressionMode(ImageWriteParam.MODE_EXPLICIT);
    par.setCompressionQuality(0.75f);

    f = new File("TestImageIOExplicity");
    f.mkdir();
    for (int i = 0; i < numTest; i++) {
        f = new File("TestImageIOExplicity\\test" + i + ".jpg");
        FileImageOutputStream output = new FileImageOutputStream(f);
        writer.setOutput(output);
        IIOImage img = new IIOImage(image, null, null);
        writer.write(null, img, par);
        output.close();
    }

    t2 = System.currentTimeMillis();
    writer.dispose();
    System.out.println("IMAGEIOPAR");
    System.out.println("Total time:: " + (t2 - t1) + " average time:: " + (t2 - t1) / numTest);
```

For the code above my result test are below in ms.

```
JPEGCODEC 
Total time:: 13750 average time:: 68
ImageIO
Total time:: 38906 average time:: 194
IMAGEIOPAR
Total time:: 43078 average time:: 215
```

I know that i should´t use the com.sun.image.codec.jpeg.JPEGCodec , but with this kind of results, it makes the use of ImageIO for encoding/writing jpg unbearable.In my current project the difference in average encoding and writing is so great that i must use JPEGCODEC, or use another external library for the same effect.

Comment: Thanks for your input, in my case the performance difference was not a factor given the volume/frequency of processing.